# page opening in both window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have one submit button in my page , where i wanted to open that link in different window .

check this code

```
  <input class="btn add-to-cart-btn" onclick="one();two();" type="submit" value="More Info At {{ product.vendor }}"/>
```

java script code

```
<script>
  function one(){
   trackOutboundLink('{{ product.metafields.google.custom_label_0 }}');


}

function two(){
    window.open('{{ product.metafields.google.custom_label_0 }}');

}


  var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'outgoing', 'click', url, {
    'transport': 'beacon',
    'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
  });
    }
</script>
```

the "product.metafields.google.custom_label_0" is a static url .

if i click that submit page then that link is opening in new window as well as same window .

But i wanted to open in different window only . how to control this ?

Comment: yup. you are correct

Comment: But what about my another function .? if add that function in two() then same problem

Comment: i have updated my question please check

Comment: ga() its google analytic event function

Comment: same thing i am doing . but its not working

Comment: Yes same result ... check here  https://www.trendsnaps.com/products/a-initial-necklace

Comment: finally . i can :) thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem lies here:-

`'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}`

What happen that on button click first `one();` and then `two();` function called. So after opening the new window again, the original URL reloaded by the above code of function `trackOutboundLink()` which is called in function `one();`

So simple remove it or comment it like below:-

```
<input class="btn add-to-cart-btn" onclick="one();two();" type="submit" value="More Info At {{ product.vendor }}"/>

<script>
  function one(){
   trackOutboundLink('{{ product.metafields.google.custom_label_0 }}');
}

function two(){
    window.open('{{ product.metafields.google.custom_label_0 }}');
}

var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'outgoing', 'click', url, {
    'transport': 'beacon',
    /* 'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;} */
  });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

You can try : `var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=200,height=100");` for open an about:blank page in a new window.

You have to set windows size.

Comment: i am trying to prevent opening link in same window . check this out trendsnaps.com/products/a-initial-necklace

Answer (score 0):

Change input type from "submit" to "button"

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax**

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)
```

Try this

```
window.open("product.metafields.google.custom_label_0 ", "_blank");
```

[more Info](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)